# Data not fitted to Basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap, map-projections, grib

When I try to plot data using Basemap from a Grib file, the map is not fitted to the data being plotted. I posted the code used below and and a link to the output image below that. I think the projection type might be the issue.
I also tried making the projection cylindrical while keeping the rest of the code the same, but that didn't work either (though it looked a little better) and I posted a link to the output image for that as well. Maybe this helps to visualize what projection will properly fit the data?
Any ideas as to what you think might have gone wrong would be appreciated.

```
from pprint import pprint
import pygrib
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from ncepgrib2 import Grib2Decode


file = 'hrrr.t00z.wrfsfcf00.grib2'
gr = pygrib.open(file)


msg = gr[32] #Temperature values in Kelvin
#print(Grib2Decode(msg.tostring(),gribmsg=True))#Similar to printing all info for netCDF file
Temp = msg.values

lat, lon = msg.latlons()

m=Basemap(projection='lcc',llcrnrlon=lon.min(), \
  urcrnrlon=lon.max(),llcrnrlat=lat.min(),urcrnrlat=lat.max(), \
  lat_0 = float(msg['latitudeOfFirstGridPointInDegrees']),lon_0 =float(msg['longitudeOfFirstGridPointInDegrees']) ,resolution='c')

x,y = m(lon,lat)


                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          #m = Basemap(width=11297120.0,height=8959788.0,
#           resolution='c',projection='lcc',\
#            lat_ts=40,lat_0=lat_0,lon_0=lon_0)



fig = plt.figure(figsize = (18.6,10.5))
cs = m.pcolormesh(x,y,(Temp-273.15)*9/5 +32,cmap = plt.cm.jet)
m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawstates()
m.drawcountries()
plt.colorbar(cs,orientation='vertical')
plt.title('Temperature F')
plt.savefig('plot')
plt.show()
```

[Image of output using lcc projection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmD5f.jpg)
[Image of output using cylindrical projection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NanOr.jpg)
[Link to HRRR data containing Grib file. All are in the exact same format, projection, etc... so you could download any one of them and get the same results (just different Temperature values)](http://home.chpc.utah.edu/%7Eu0553130/Brian_Blaylock/cgi-bin/hrrr_download.cgi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways to solve your problem:

1. Setting xlim and ylim which is the easiest way for you:

```
plt.xlim([min_lon, max_lon])
plt.ylim([min_lat, max_lat])
```

2. Use cfgrib+xarray to plot directly from the xarray object

Comment: Could you provide a quick example of how to use cfgrib+xarray . I am unfamiliar with them so I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean when you say that you can "plot directly from the xarray object". Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. Install cfgrib as mentioned here https://github.com/ecmwf/cfgrib  2. install xarray via pip 3. open grib file ` data = xarray.open_dataset('file_path', engine='cfgrib')`4. Follow this guide to plot http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/plotting.html

Comment: I tried to do this and I got an error: cfgrib.dataset.DatasetBuildError: multiple values for key 'typeOfLevel'. It looks like this is an issue with cfgrib not being able to handle the data if it has multiple levels. Are you able to take one of the HRRR files and run it through xarray using the cfgrib engine?

Comment: You can filter parameteres by adding the following:  `backend_kwargs={'filter_by_keys': {'typeOfLevel': 'surface'}}`. And you can use cfgrib function `open_datasets` to get a list of xarrays with the whole dataset seperated in xarrays.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I tried that and got the following error:                  DatasetBuildError: multiple values for unique key, try re-open the file with one of:
    filter_by_keys={'stepType': 'instant', 'typeOfLevel': 'surface'}
    filter_by_keys={'stepType': 'accum', 'typeOfLevel': 'surface'}                                             I fixed it by adding `'steptype': 'instant'`. So the line of code that worked in its entirety was: `data = xr.open_dataset(file, engine = 'cfgrib', filter_by_keys={'stepType': 'instant', 'typeOfLevel': 'surface'})`

Comment: Using `'accum'` also worked and was much faster. Here's the full line of code: `data = xr.open_dataset(file, engine = 'cfgrib', filter_by_keys={'stepType': 'accum', 'typeOfLevel': 'surface'})`

Comment: It is a bit tricky to find the correct filter. Would be great to earn kudos for my comment if it helped you.

Comment: I did give your answer an upvote, but I don't think my reputation is high enough for it to count. I also don't see an option to upvote your comments. I'm sort of brand new to Stackoverflow so maybe that's why. Your input has definitely solved the problem though.